# Where do you find each of the pouch expansions?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Since you get a few through the main story (but not enough for each character), where can you find the rest of the pouch expansions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six in total that you can find (one for each party member throughout the game). Here is where you get each of them:

1. You'll receive this one in the main story during chapter 2 from

> killing Dughall.

2. You'll receive this one in the main story during chapter 6 from

> killing Giga Rosa.

3. After the story event in the bandit cave in Gormott, you'll find this in a chest.
4. > When you've been to Leftheria, you can skip travel to Godford Isle, turn around and drop onto the moving platform. It will pass by one platform that has a collection node, but when you go farther north you'll find another platform with a chest on it containing the 4th expansion.
5. > At the end of Spirit Crucible Elpys (in the Vault of Heroes area, underneath the staircase), you can find the 5th expansion. This one will require a skill check.
6. > When you can access the Beruf Industry Ward in Mor Ardain (NE, Alba Cavanich) you can ride a moving cargo container to a cliff off to the side. There is a key obtained by doing the quest We Meet Again which is required to access the factory.

[source](https://www.rpgsite.net/feature/6464-xenoblade-chronicles-2-pouch-items-and-where-to-find-the-pouch-expansions)

Why are there 6 instead of 5 (the number of party slots you have)?

> Vandham dies, so just in case you used one on him, you can still get an additional one later.

Comment: For the story-based expansions, which chapters are they found in?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro added.

Comment: If someone is searching “where do you find the expansion pouches”, it’s not a spoiler to say where to find them. You can say “you earn these from chapter X after <spoiler>killing character <spoiler>

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I don't think you can do inline spoilers as you suggest, but I'll format it a different way.